# Is it possible to make up a parabola by adding up infinitely many parabolas at different points?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Is such an integral possible and if it is, what is/are the function(s) f(t) satisfying that equation?

$$x^2 = \int_{-\infty }^{+\infty } f(t)(x-t)^2dt$$

Comment: In this case you can use Dirac delta function $f(t)=\delta(t)$

Comment: expand the term in the parenthesis, and integrate each term. if all integral converge, you are done.

Comment: in here, I am trying to use all the parabolas whose minima lie throughout the real axis, to add them up (or get a weighted average) and get x^2. f(t) is the weight of this weighted average. δ(t) might work for it gives all the weight to the parabola at zero to get x^2. But I need a f(t) such that the contribution of the other -than that at zero- parabolas is comparable to the contribution of the parabola at zero, which is not the case for δ(t) since it is as if the contribution of the parabola at zero is infinite whereas others are zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in a comment, any $f$ such that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\,dt=1$, and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\,t\,dt=0$, and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\,t^2\,dt=0$ will do...

Assuming $f$ has a Fourier transform that makes sense pointwise, this is equivalent to saying that $\widehat{f}(0)=1$, $\widehat{f'}(0)=0$, and $\widehat{f''}(0)=0$, so $\widehat{f}$ can be any nice function just satisfying these three conditions at $0$. Then use Fourier inversion.